# What should I do If a user gives the same answer as other user?

Tags: discussion

So I have access to review queues now...Every now and then when I come across a 'first answer', I use to open the thread in new tab and check out the whole thread. Some times it happens that the answer under review is a duplicate of an answer on the same thread by some other user (or at least it is not adding any significant improvement in other user answer i.e. a bit of variable name changes in code, nothing else).

What should be my response?

1. Leave it alone... just check that the answer is of acceptable quality. (Anyway if I don't open the thread in new tab, I would never know it is a duplicate)
2. Add comment telling user that it is duplicate of xyz user's answer.
3. Down-vote / flag it!!?

Comment: If it is plagiarism custom mod flag it ensuring you explain that it is such and include the link of the other answer. I personally would also leave a comment but it's not expected or required in these instances.

Comment: If it's plagiarism, flag it and alert a moderator. Otherwise, just downvote it and optionally add a comment. In the review queue, I would recommend recommending deletion.

Comment: @CodyGray of course that is if it's in the LQ queue. The First Post queue doesn't offer the option to recommend deletion. But yeah, I would definitely flag.

Comment: Thanks Bugs, Cody Gray.. I wonder why the duplicate question didn't appear in my search / related questions while I was typing the title / question.

Comment: Oh, well, I can't keep up, @Bugs. From my vantage point, *every* queue should offer the ability to recommend deletion!